# seems data missing in scp

Tags: disk-usage

I copy a directory from one server to other server, I check data both way in order to know nothing is missing, actually no data is missing but when I use `du -sc ....` the volume is not the same, see below:

source server:

```
[sensage@drl520 dwf_dump]$ du -sc azar94 
99016492        azar94
99016492        total
```

destination server:

```
[sensage@sensage4 dwf_backup]$ du -sc azar94    
99016376        azar94
99016376        total
```

source server:

```
[sensage@drl520 dwf_dump]$ du -shc azar94
95G     azar94
95G     total
```

destination server:

```
[sensage@sensage4 dwf_backup]$ du -shc azar94
95G     azar94
95G     total
```

these directories is full of zip files, for example:

```
[sensage@sensage4 Incoming_query]$ find . -iname "*.gz"
./result/IN/Complete/Markazi/ARAK_Incoming_comp.txt.gz
./result/IN/Complete/Markazi/Markazi_Incoming_comp.txt.gz
./result/IN/Complete/Yazd/YAZDTX_Incoming_comp.txt.gz
./result/IN/Complete/Yazd/Yazd_Incoming_comp.txt.gz
./result/IN/Complete/Tehran/Tehran_Incoming_etc_comp.txt.gz
./result/IN/Complete/Tehran/Tehran_Incoming_comp.txt.gz
./result/IN/Complete/Tehran/TCT_Incoming_comp.txt.gz
./result/IN/Complete/TKC/TKCsms_Incoming_comp.txt.gz
./result/IN/Complete/TKC/TKCVoice_Incoming_comp.txt.gz
............................
```

I tracked the mismatches from both side and I actually sure that nothing is missing and both data are the same but I wonder what's the explanation for mismatch of output of `du -sc ...`

Comment: Maybe one reason is the size of your directory. When copying/moving/deleting files within a directory, the directory size itself changes. But directory sizes only grow. When you now copy the directory to another place it is newly created and will have a different size than the original one.

Comment: `du` shows the space used by files on disk, not the total length of files.  The space used on disk can vary for many reasons, such as deleted files in either source or destination directories, different inode or block sizes, some files being sparse etc.  Use `MD5` to check data integrity.

Comment: use `-b` options, if you want to compare the apparent size in byte